# fetch rails-assets very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64:/vagrant$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/.
Fetching source index from https://ruby.taobao.org/
Fetching source index from https://rails-assets.org/
```

Stuck here more than 10 minutes, it used to wait very long time for it done. But I did not install new gem of rails-assets in this case.

Is the rails-assets server problem? Or mine?

here is my gem setting:

```
gem 'bundler', '>= 1.8.4'
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-bsie'
  gem 'rails-assets-font-awesome'
end
```

Comment: What didn't install, exactly?

Comment: Recently when I use the VPN it works fine. Maybe it's network problem.